# Using constant current and constant voltage power supply with LED strips

Tags: led-driver, led-strip, constant-current

I have a Meanwell 12V power supply ([ELG-200-12](https://www.meanwell-web.com/content/files/pdfs/productPdfs/MW/ELG-200/ELG-200-spec.pdf)) which is constant voltage and constant current.

[image]

Note 2:

[image]

I want to power t one 5 meter 12V LED strip that consume 11.52W/m with it.

The specifications for the [LED strips](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000876742043.html) are:

[image]

From the little bit of electronics that I know is that the current is consumed by the LED strip as it needs it, which basically mean that I can use a higher rated PSU as long as the voltage is the same. Since I have a constant current PSU I wonder whether it would damage the LED strip.

Comment: LED strips rarely use constant current power supplies.  Post a link or datasheet for the strip you are using.

Comment: What does "Note 2" say?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I've updated the question,

Comment: A naked LED would prefer constant current, but what user1850479 said is true because a typical LED strip is more than just naked LEDs. It contains other components (often, just resistors) that ensure current within some acceptable range when given a constant voltage of some particular value.

Comment: I would describe that power supply as "current limiting" rather than "constant current" - it is designed to supply 12 volts at up to 10 amps.  If the load requires more than 10 amps, the supply will reduce the voltage as needed to keep the current at 10 amps.  It is appropriate for your use.  Your LED strip will only draw about 4.8 amp.

Comment: @user1850479 I've updated the question with the specs of the LED strip

Comment: @PeterBennett If I get what you wrote correctly the 'constant current' is from the PSU side only, the LED strip will draw the amounts it needs. 
I like term 'current limiting' since in the specs of the PSU you can see that the current has a region between 6~12V.

Comment: On that supply, the current limit/"constant current" is intended to limit current in a fault condition, to protect the power supply.  The supply shouldn't normally be operated in that state.